# Chrome throws a cross-origin error when accessing contentDocument of an iframe in the same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, same-origin-policy

I've encountered a weird problem that only seems to affect Google Chrome.

I'm helping my fellow developer to build a simple portfolio page that hosts HTML5 banners. The way it works is as follows:

Upon loading the page, you're presented with the list of clients. After clicking one of them, a bootstrap modal opens, inside which there's a carousel with examples of HTML5 banners created for that client. Each of them is loaded inside an iframe that's contained within each carousel slide.

Now, the banner is only meant to play when the slide is active. To achieve that, the developer has added two listeners to the carousel element:

slid.bs.carousel and shown.bs.modal

The handler for each of those is the same: it checks if the iframe is loaded and if so, posts a "play" message to it:

```
function postMessageToIframe(iframe, message) {
    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

    if (iframeDoc.readyState  == 'complete' ) {
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, iframe.src);
        return;
    }

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        postMessageToIframe(iframe, message);
    }, 100);
}
```

and

```
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    postMessageToIframe($(this).find('.active.item iframe')[0], 'play');
});
```

Now, this works perfectly fine across the board, except for Google Chrome, which throws the following error:

> Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from
>   'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://xxxx from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Here's what's weird:

1. It only does that for **some banners**, while other open and play fine
2. The **domain is the same** and **so is the protocol and port**
3. There's no document.domain or any such thing present in any of the banners and there's no .htaccess file with any special rules

Any ideas?

Comment: And you've tried adding a `console.log(iframe.src)` to the top of `postMessageToIframe` to ensure it's exactly what you think it is in that moment? Off the top of my head my ideas: human error, race condition, chrome bug.

Comment: Yup, I did precisely that. I even wrapped it all inside try/catch routine to see if it would "correct itself", but to no avail, it just spams the same error over and over again even tho console.log(iframe.src) inside catch reports the same domain. Right now I'm leaning towards Chrome bug, but perhaps I'm missing something (it's late).

Comment: and it's always the same `iframe.src`s that trigger this? or are they different everytime you try it?

Comment: Same sub-domain as well? `http://app.domain.com:80` and `http://www.domain.com:80` will fail unless you use `document.domain` on both child and parent page.

Comment: It's all hosted inside the main domain and from the same folder. Each and every one of them.

Let's say the main landing page is hosted at http://xxxx/

Banners are loaded from:

http://xxxx/client-name/banner-1/
http://xxxx/another-client-name/banner-1/

What drives me mad is that it seems to be completely random. There are two nearly identical banners for the same client (except their size) and yet one of them throws an error, while the other one loads fine. Both on the same server, same domain, port, and path, except the final subdir.

Comment: Have you compared the response headers for one that works against one that doesn't?

Comment: *What drives me mad is that it seems to be completely random.* If it's a random occurrence (especially if an iframe fails once then doesn't the next time,) it's more than likely your carousel script is ran before all of the iframes are loaded. Try `window.onload = function() {....`

Comment: That's the whole point of the postMessageToIframe function - to only post message once the iframe is loaded.

Comment: It looks as if `postMessage()` is setup correctly for one iframe but not each iframe. So sure the first iframe loaded is detected but none of the other ones are.